# getting list of files in Python

Tags: python

I use the following line to get list of directories of a given path in python:

```
os.listdir("directory")
```

And it returns a list of directories, but I can't figure out how to get the list of files a directory?

Answer (score 2):

`os.listdir()` lists all *names* in a directory. This includes both files and subdirectories.

Take into account these names are all relative to the listed directory. Use `os.path.join()` to build full paths, and use `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.isdir()` to filter the list.

Comment: thanks I got my problem